# GoogleBot can't reach my site

Tags: robots.txt, googlebot

For some reason, the other day, out of nowhere, Google Webmaster Tools started showing all these errors while crawling my site, saying that it couldn't reach my pages. I checked my *robots.txt* and talked to my hosting provider and everything checks out, so I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Can you post the error displayed by google?

Comment: Is your page still found when you google it? Does clicking on the Google list items bring you to your site?

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing the same issue across multiple dedicated servers in different datacenters.

Matt Cutts posted on his blog that this looks like a Google issue. I wouldn't freak out unless it continues for another couple days.

Comment: Can you link me to the blog post?